# How to write nested enumerates nicely

Tags: environments, enumerate, enumitem

I'm writing solutions to some problems in LaTeX. My finished answers look a little like:

```
1. (a)  (i) Something
       (ii) Something else
   (b) More things
2. (a) Stuff
```

Writing this out, even with consistent indentation, makes the following mess:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setenumerate[1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.}}
\setenumerate[2]{label=(\alph*)}
\setenumerate[3]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
            \item \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Something
                    \item Something else
                  \end{enumerate}
            \item More things
          \end{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
            \item Stuff
          \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is there some way to write this out in a more readable/maintainable way? Perhaps some environment so that I could write

```
\begin{awesomenumerate}
    \item3 Something
    \item3 Something else
    \item2 More things
    \new1
    \item2 Stuff
\end{awesomenumerate}
```

Comment: (1) welcome. (2) in my opinion the environment way is the best as the semantics is clearly visible. Your `awesomenumerate` env will end up being a mess that is hard for the user to comprehend.

Comment: You could check the easylist package.

Comment: @daleif I agree that my environment isn't a good way of doing it, but with some better indentation and possibly syntax I think it would be much easier to read and maintain in my MWE.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that looks great - I'll check it out.